# free space in horizontal scroll view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a linear layout in my horizontal scroll view and I want to show images dynamically in it. This is my code:

```
if (imgs.size() != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); i++) {
        File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                              + "/shafa/" 
                              + imgs.get(i)
                                    .replace(" ", "+")
                                    .replace(".jpg", "")
                                    .replace(".JPG", "")
                                    .replace(".png", ""));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            textview9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView image = new ImageView(DrugActivity.this);
            image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            imgslayout.addView(image);
            imgslayout.setGravity(0);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                image.setElevation(15);
            }
            image.setLayoutParams(lp);
            image.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

And layout code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/imgslayout"
        android:padding="10dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I dont want that free space in scroll view

Comment: Post the layout code...

Comment: sorry. post edited @SagiLow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the scroll view height to 220dp but set the `ImageView image` height & width to `MATCH_PARENT`.
Android keeps the ImageView aspect ratio by default so it fills the height but can't fill the width hence the free space.
You can either use `setBackground` (but not with `Bitmap` directly) or remove the height restriction, or set `image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);` (which will stretch the image)

Comment: i cant use setbackground because maybe some of the drugs has more than 1 picture and cant delete scroll view height. so what should i do?

Comment: I wrote another option (`image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`) but the image aspect ratio will not be preserved. You can also set the gravity to center so there will be space on some images but the image will be centered.

Comment: but i cant change the aspect ratio. there is no way to fix this? thats not feels good

Comment: Well, I guess you can also match the width and let the height get cropped. I'm afraid these are all the options you have my friend.  You can't have it all..

Comment: thanks i did it with another trick. do you have any idea about elevation? image dont have shadow

Comment: Try setting `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the `ImageView` parent